# How to add second device in layout manager Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on Android Studio. I know Android Studio supports Preview all screen.

[image]

But I don't need to see all devices ? Can I use two devices for layout editor ? All I want to do is   Nexus 5 and 10.1 inch Nexus tablet for layout manager.

How can I add more than one device ?

Thanks for replies.